# Custom interval expression for the Vertical Axis Major Tick Marks in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

I am creating a chart in my **Business Intelligence Development Studio** for **SSRS 2008 R2**.  I am having an issue with the **Vertical Axis Major Tick Marks**.  When left on **Auto**, it sets the Major Tick Marks at every 2 million.  I am wanting them every 1 million.  How do I go about creating an expression that will accomplish this?

[image: my chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it adjusted by setting the **Maximum Value** to:

**SUM** of the **Y-Axis** field plus **1,000,000**.